# AS3: strategy for adding sprites that animate sequentially

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

I am developing a component that can list files that users select from their filesystem. I'm using a (extended) FileReferenceList and (my own) FileReferenceDisplayList. The latter listens for events from the former.
If the FileReferenceDisplayList receives a FileReferenceListEvent.ADDED event, it should display the new item in the displaylist. However, when multiple files are added at once I want to animate them sequentially in stead of at the same time. What would be the best strategy for making sure the items are animated with small pauses between them?

I thought about putting newly added items in a queue and then polling the queue for existing items with an Event.ENTER_FRAME. But maybe you can suggest another method that doesn't need to make use of Event.ENTER_FRAME?

**Edit**
I guess I forgot to mention that the part that puzzles me the most how I can set some timeout if multiple files are added. Maybe I should use the queue's length to multiply the timeouts for the items? So, if a file is added, I set the animation timeout for that item to be multiplied by the current length of the queue? (Just thinking out loud here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at TimeLineLite from Greensock - http://blog.greensock.com/timelinelite/

> insertMultiple() and appendMultiple()
>   provide some very powerful sequencing
>   tools, allowing you to add an Array of
>   tweens or timelines and optionally
>   align them with SEQUENCE or START
>   modes, and even stagger them if you
>   want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer but why not stick with the ENTER_FRAME.